# How to write backtick in iPhone 6s?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, iphone

As you know, backtick ( ` ) is needed to mark down the code blocks when writing any answer / comment in stackoverflow or any other stackexchange sites. But I am struggling to find out the key to write backtick when using my iPhone.

I am new to iPhone and using iPhone 6s. Thanks for your help in advance.